# NoClassDefFoundError for JavacTaskImpl

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that will take advantage of the Tree API (see https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/16/hacking-javac). The basic idea is that you create a [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and use that to get a [`JavaCompiler.CompilationTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.CompilationTask.html).  The `CompilationTask` that gets returned is actually an instance of `JavacTaskImpl` (See the code below).  But when I try to cast the returned `CompilationTask` to a `JavacTaskImpl`, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

import com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects("Test.java");
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, fileObjects);

        // Prove that this is indeed an instance of JavacTaskImpl.
        System.out.println("Task.getClass(): " + task.getClass());

        JavacTaskImpl javacTask = (JavacTaskImpl) task;
    }
}
```

You can compile this code with

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac Main.java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

But running the code using

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java Main -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

produces the following output:

```
Task.getClass(): class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/api/JavacTaskImpl
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 1 more
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the options in `JavaCompiler.getTask` (see [JavaCompiler javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)). The easiest way is to use the System property:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjects("Test.java");
        String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, 
                Arrays.asList("-classpath", classPath),
                null, fileObjects);

        // Prove that this is indeed an instance of JavacTaskImpl.
        System.out.println("Task.getClass(): " + task.getClass());

        JavacTaskImpl javacTask = (JavacTaskImpl) task;
    }
}
```